# How do I get case drops in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've been playing Counter-Strike: Global Offensive for about a month and never got a case. I've even tried idling. Do you have to be MVP? How does it work for CS:GO?

Answer (score 4):

The loot at the end of a match is totally random. You cannot influence what you get.

An excerpt from this [guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=170746735):

You get around 2-8 items per week, on an average while you can get 2-4 items per day. Loot only drops on VAC protected servers and as I said, it is totally random. Your score does not affect your drops at all. So you can suck royally at a match and still get a valuable item.

> On a not so serious side note: You can try to pray to RNGesus.

Comment: Sucking royally and getting an item. you're not wrong there. once got 4 kills in a whole 30 round comp and got a case drop from it. the only drop of the whole game.